# What is the implication of the existence of a non-singular matrix $S: \gamma^\lambda S=S \gamma^m u$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, linear-algebra, dirac-matrices, textbook-erratum

> $$\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu+\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu=2g^{\mu\nu}I_4$$
>
> Pauli's fundamental theorem states that given two sets of matrices $\gamma^\mu$ and $\gamma^\nu$ which obey the commutation rules (above), then there must exist a non-singular matrix $S$ such that
>   $$\gamma^\lambda S=S \gamma^m u$$

I don't understand what it means by there must exist a non-singular matrix $S$. And where do the u in the above equation come from?

$\gamma^\mu=\gamma^0+\gamma^i$, $\gamma^0=\beta$, $\gamma^i=\beta\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\alpha$ are Dirac matrices.

[Source](http://www.academia.edu/11352470/The_Dirac_Equation_Derivation_and_Physical_Interpretation)-Page 14

Comment: Its a typos. $u$ should not be there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question (v4) because it seems based on a simple typo. To reopen this question, consider to provide proper reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-singular matrix has an inverse one, so its determinant does not equal zero. And there should be no $u$ there, I guess it's an artifact of a Latex error in $\mu$, so it should be $\gamma^{\mu}$.